# Matching micro-strip line to load and generator

Tags: homework, trace, microstrip, matching

I have the following system.
[image]

I need to add stubs/ reactive components to the trace (L2) to match the generator to the load.

I understand that due to Z_trace being a micro-strip that its consists of capacitive, inductive, resistive and conductance components, which need to be calculated to provide a complex impedance of the trace.

I am however unsure how to use smith charts to work back to matching the trace to the load.

As I am used to the transmission line being for example 50 Ohms and the Load being the complex impedance. Does it work in the same way? Where i would normalize the Z_load to be 1, and then normalize Z_trace, piloting it. Then find the component (reactive/ capative etc) to then match it?